# scipy interp2d crashes for not being able to allocate memory, any alternative?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to interpolate, at some user-defined, continuous, 2D x,y position, the value of a 2D function, defined on a regular cartesian mesh (i,j).

What I've tried, is using the function interp2d from scipy.interpolate, to get a function that would, by interpolating with an appropriate model, return a value of f at (x,y).

See the doc :

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html

The following code reproduces an error that I have. It seems that interp2d crashes because it can't allocate that much memory.

any idea how that could be done otherwise ?

```
   import scipy.interpolate as interp
   import numpy as np


   def main():
       x = np.arange(4098)/4097.
       z = np.arange(1602)/1601.

       xx,zz = np.meshgrid(x,z)
       f = np.sin(xx**2 + zz**2)

       ff = interp.interp2d(x,z,f, kind='linear')


   if __name__ == '__main__':
       main()
```

Comment: Are you getting the error with exactly the code shown above, with those size arrays?  How much memory do you have?  `f`, `xx` and `zz` are under 54 megabytes each.  `interp2d` should have no problem with that.

Comment: I have the error with the code posted above, with those sizes yes. I get this error : 

1.0 1.0
(1602, 4098) (1602, 4098)
(1602, 4098)
Python(25673) malloc: *** mmap(size=18446744062377512960) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region

Comment: Something is seriously wrong there, and I don't think it is interp2d.  What OS are you using?  32 or 64 bit?  How did you install numpy and scipy?

Comment: mac os 10.6.8 64bit numpy (1.6.2) and scipy (0.11.0) installed with macports (2.1.2).

Comment: A couple more questions: Is python from macports also?  What is the output of running `python -c "from scipy import interpolate; interpolate.test()"` in a terminal?

Comment: yes python is from macports too. The result of your command is : http://pastebin.com/DFwWTieA

Comment: Argh... I forgot that I've been using the development version of scipy, and your code works fine with that.  When I go back to scipy 0.11 (and 0.10.1), python crashes with a "Memory error" (this is in Linux).  So this is apparently a bug in interp2d that appears to have been fixed since 0.11.  More later...

Comment: ok I'll check other versions then

Comment: See the answer by @pv.  You code works fine with scipy 0.12.0.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that the spline fitting routine makes an extremely pessimistic estimate of how much space is needed in the knot selection (this algorithm: http://netlib.org/dierckx/surfit.f, see description of lwrk2 and do the math in the pessimistic way --- it gives ~200 GB).

Note that this is an *unstructured data* interpolation routine --- interp2d can also be passed input data that's not on a regular grid. 4098*1602=6564996 is a rather large number of data points for scattered data interpolation, even though it is easily manageable if the data is regularly arranged on a grid, as in this case.

How this works [was changed](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/commit/7adfbbda57ede6) in Scipy 0.12.0, in which interp2d deduces in this case that the data is on a rectangular grid, and uses a more efficient algorithm in this special case.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need such a fine meshgrid? You could save memory by reducing the granularity of the grid.

This makes `x` range from 0 to 1 whith 100 equally spaced points:

```
   x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
```

---

```
import scipy.interpolate as interp
import numpy as np


def main():
   x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
   z = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)

   xx,zz = np.meshgrid(x,z)
   f = np.sin(xx**2 + zz**2)

   ff = interp.interp2d(x,z,f, kind='linear')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Yeah, I get the grid from a simulation and do need it with this resolution.